# Docxtemplater - Newlines between loop iterations

Tags: docxtemplater

TLDR - how do I use either a custom parser function or modify the loop module to it'll add a newline after each iteration?

Long story:

I'm using old templates that used to be rendered with some MS tools, now trying to render them with docxtemplater. Main requirement is to not modify the templates. Use them as they are, and be able to render documents as identical as possible to that MS tool.

Here's what a loop looks like in one of the templates:

```
«TableStart:MortgageInfo»« MortgageInfo_Name»
« MortgageInfo_MortgageStreet»
«CityStateZip»«TableEnd:MortgageInfo»
```

I used custom delimiters for `«` and `»` and created a custom loop module to handle the custom `TableStart:` and `TableEnd:` format.

There is no linebreak between `«CityStateZip»` and `«TableEnd:MortgageInfo»` so the 2nd item is rendered immediately after the 1st without a linebreak.

Anybody has any idea how I add this missing linebreak? Please bare in mind - no modification to the template is allowed...